# How to Load Fragment if it is not Null - Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need some help as I am a bit new in android, in my android app that I am working on, I am navigating between Fragments all the time. I use the code to navigate between Fragments.

```
 private void displaySelectedScreen(int id){
        Fragment fragment=null;
        String fragment_tag="";
        switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.nav_listen:
                fragment=new ListenFragment();
                fragment_tag="LISTENTAG";
                break;
            case R.id.nav_programs:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_stories:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_feedback:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                shareTextUrl();
                break;
        }
        if(fragment!=null){
            FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment,fragment_tag);
            ft.commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
```

I just need to check that if the fragment exists(loaded) before, containter should show the previously loaded fragment. However, if the Fragment was not loaded before the Fragment should be loaded for the first time.

Could anyone help me about making this happen?

Thank you very much.
Code inside my fragment:(ListenFragment.java)

```
public class ListenFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Listen Live");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View InputFragmentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listen_layout,container,false);

        return InputFragmentView;
    }
```

Comment: In `ListenFragment`, the check-condition can be if `view != null` then...Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It would be great if you could show me a sample, Pleaseas I am a bit new in android.

Comment: I just want that the ListenFragment does't create everytime i navigate back to that fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the variables reference to Fragment's instance. Instead, save your fragment by tag then get it. Like that:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag");
if(fragment == null) {
   fragment=new ListenFragment();
}
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment_tag);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Thank You so much it worked!. You save my lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

use below methods to get the Fragment:

> getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.is.xyz)
>
> getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTAG("XYZ")

then use to start Fragment :

> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

there is a similar question here it might help:
[Check if a fragment exists and reuse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567470/check-if-a-fragment-exists-and-reuse-it)